# How to XOR two expressions of `test`?

Tags: shell, filenames, test

I need to check that a directory (let's call it `dir`) contains one of two files (let's call them `filea` and `fileb`), but neither none nor both.

The ideal solution would be to use a XOR operation between the predicates:

```
if [ -f dir/filea ] ^ [ -f dir/fileb]
then
    echo Structure ok
    # do stuff
fi
```

However the shell does not support the `^` as a XOR operator, and the `[` command does not have the options `-X` or `--xor` like it has `-a` and `-o`... Using a negated equality did not work either:

```
if ! [ -f dir/filea -eq -f dir/fileb ]
# or
if ! [ -f dir/filea = -f dir/fileb ]
```

Is there some way to achieve this, without resorting to a full-blown AND/OR expression like

```
if { [ -f dir/filea ] || [ -f dir/fileb ]; } && ! { [ -f dir/filea ] && [ -f dir/fileb ]; }
```

?

The last expression is becoming unreadable, and *of course* my actual paths are much longer than `dir/fileX`.

**EDIT:** I am targetting a POSIX-compliant version of `sh`, but I am open to extensions specific to other shells (out of curiosity mostly, but also because I use `bash` or `ksh93` on other projects and this could be useful there)

Comment: Related: [XOR in shell globs](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/635287)

Comment: @joH1 could you please indicate which shell you want answers for? Do you need a strict POSIX sh answer, or are you writing for Bash or Dash or Ksh or Zsh or some other shell?

Answer (score 17):

The exit code of a `test ...` or `[ ... ]` command is the test result. You can use variables to store the result of individual tests and compare them later.

```
[ -f dir/filea ]
testA=$?
[ -f dir/fileb ]
testB=$?
if [ "$testA" -ne "$testB" ]
then
   echo "exactly one file"
else
   echo "both files or none"
fi
```

It might be possible that `[` results in different non-zero exit codes for the two tests.
<sub>According to the specification in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/test.html, an exit code `>1` means "An error occurred." You have to define what should happen if `[` reports an error.</sub>

To avoid this you can use conditional variable assignments similar to [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704492/330217) ...

```
testA=0
testB=0
[ -f dir/filea ] || testA=1
[ -f dir/fileb ] || testB=1
if [ "$testA" -ne "$testB" ]
then
   echo "exactly one file"
else
   echo "both files or none"
fi
```

... or use negation (as mentioned in comments) to make sure the value is either `0` or `1`.
<sub>(See "2.9.2 Pipelines" - "Exit Status" in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02)</sub>

```
! [ -f dir/filea ]
testA=$?
! [ -f dir/fileb ]
testB=$?
if [ "$testA" -ne "$testB" ]
then
   echo "exactly one file"
else
   echo "both files or none"
fi
```

Both variants handle an error the same as "file does not exist".

Comment: Great idea, thanks. It has the advantage of allowing to reuse the variables as flags if needed.

Answer (score 5):

The following uses the arithmetic XOR operator `^` on the values of `a` and `b`.  These variables are 1 if the corresponding file exists and is a regular file; otherwise, they are zero.

```bash
a=0
b=0

[ -f dir/filea ] && a=1
[ -f dir/fileb ] && b=1

[ "$(( a ^ b ))" -eq 1 ] && echo OK
```

Another approach is to count the number of times the test succeeds:

```bash
ok=0

[ -f dir/filea ] && ok=$(( ok + 1 ))
[ -f dir/fileb ] && ok=$(( ok + 1 ))

[ "$ok" -eq 1 ] && echo OK
```

Comment: We don't yet know whether @joH1 is looking for a strict POSIX sh answer, but if so, it should be noted that `$(( a ^ b ))` isn't POSIX compliant; you need `$(( $a ^ $b ))` instead - which is sad, because using `$` inside `$((...))` opens a can of precedence worms.

Comment: @MartinKealey, that's not true `$(( a ^ b ))` is POSIX and generally preferred (things like `$(($a-$b))` yield undefined behaviour if `$b` is negative while `$((a-b))` is fine for instance). It's true that some (very now) old version of some ash-based shells used not to support it, and it was not always very clear in the specification.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I stand corrected, thankyou. I was looking at an ancient version of POSIX, so I'm glad that has been remedied (as usual, by sensibly accepting common practice)

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that compound commands have an exit status, just like any other command, so you can use `if a; then b; else c; fi` the same way as you'd use `a ? b : c` in most C-like languages.

Translating `a^b` ≡ `a ? !b : b` into shell, we get:

```
if if [ -f fileA ]
   then ! [ -f fileB ]
   else   [ -f fileB ]
   fi
then
   echo ONE file present
else
   echo NO or BOTH files present
fi
```

(Note that `if if` is *not* a typo.)

I'll grant that having to repeat one of the tests is a bit verbose, so I've aligned them vertically to make it clear that they're identical bar the `!` inversion.

On the plus side, this avoids messing with temporary variables holding `$?` or similar, and it's (marginally) the most performant.

Lastly, I'd note that the `-a` and `-o` options to the `test` command are problematic: they can lead to parsing ambiguities which lead to false results. Just use two test commands separated by `&&` or `||` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I would necessarily recommend that, but in `zsh`, you could do:

```
if ()(($# == 1)) dir/file[ab](N-.); then
  print "there is one regular file matching the file[ab] pattern"
fi
```

`-.` is to restrict the match to regular files after symlink resolution like your `[ -f ... ]` does. Use `(foo|bar)` for arbitrary file names.

- `() body args` is an anonymous function, the body being the ksh-style `(($# == 1))` arithmetic expression which evaluates to true if the number of arguments to the function is 1.
- `dir/file[ab](N-.)` is a glob expansion with glob qualifiers, `N` for `N`ullglob¹ so that the glob expands to nothing if there's no match, `-` for the next qualifiers to apply after symlink resolution, and `.` to restrict to files of type *regular* (as seen above).

---

<sup>¹ bash has copied the `nullglob` option from `zsh`, but not the glob qualifiers yet; ksh93 has a `~(N)` glob operator equivalent to `zsh`'s `N` glob qualifier, but no glob qualifier nor anonymous function either.</sup>

Comment: Never used zsh, so the syntax is highly hermetic to me.. I guess that is why you wouldn't recommend it ^^

Comment: In Bash one could write:```shopt -s nullglob extglob ... if ( set -- @(fileA|fileB) ; (($#==1)) ) ; then echo ONE file ; else echo MORE OR FEWER THAN ONE ; fi```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a language that supports `xor`.  e.g. with perl:

```
$ mkdir dir
$ touch dir/filea
$ perl -le 'print (((-f $ARGV[0]) xor (-f $ARGV[1])) ? 0 : 1)' dir/filea  dir/fileb
0
```

You can, of course, use command substitution to capture the output into a variable.

Or if you want the result as an exit code that you can use directly with `if`, `&&`, or `||`:

```
$ perl -le 'exit (((-f $ARGV[0]) xor (-f $ARGV[1])) ? 0 : 1)'  dir/filea  dir/fileb
$ echo $?
0
```

Note: it's important to realise that perl's definition of true (non-zero/non-empty/defined) and false (0/empty string/undefined) is different to/the opposite of shell's definition of true (0) or false (non-zero).  That's why the ternary operators above are written to return 0 when the xor evaluates as true and 1 when it evaluates as false.

That's not very important in a trivial script like this, but if you wanted to do more boolean calculations in the perl script then you'd need to keep working with perl's definition of true & false until the last moment when you return the true/false value shell expects.

BTW, if you think this is a bit odd, you're right.  It is.  It does make sense, though, and there's a good reason for it.  But Shell is the odd one out.  Most languages define true as non-zero and false as zero (and many have specific boolean data types, or only allow integers to be treated as booleans...with conversion required for other types.  perl is very flexible in what it will interpret as true/false).

Anyway, Shell does it the other way around because it mostly/often needs to know if a program exited successfully (0) or with an error code (from 1 up to 127, depending on the program, each indicating a different error condition).   It's not really true vs false, it's success vs error-code.  Any other program which needs to test the exit code returned from an external program has to do the same, regardless of the language's own internal definition of true/false.

Note 2: it's not advisable to run perl (or any external program, really) repeatedly in a shell loop.  The startup overhead might only be a few milliseconds on a fast, modern system, but that adds up with hundreds or thousands of loop iterations and makes it extremely, tediously slow.   If you absolutely must do it in a shell loop, best to find another way.  Otherwise, if you need to do the test in a loop and can't afford to fork external programs repeatedly, it's best to rewrite the whole script (or the time-sensitive parts of it) in perl or awk or python or anything-that-isn't-shell.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) for more on this topic.

Comment: BTW, not many language have unary operators for file-related tests (e.g. `-f`, `-x`, `-s`, etc.  See `perldoc -f -X`, or just `help test` in bash. the tests available are very similar but not the same). There may be others, but perl and various implementations of shell (and the standalone `test` AKA `[` binary, which exists mostly for legacy reasons as (almost?) all modern shells have `test`/`[` as a built-in) are the only ones I can think of right now. In most other languages, you'd have to use `stat()` (see `man 2 stat` if you have dev manpages installed) and process the result yourself.

Comment: Perl doesn't need an explicit `exit` as its exit status will _correctly_ reflect the truthiness of the last command, having regard for what that means in both Perl and Shell. So it suffices to write: `perl -e '1 == grep { -f $_ } @ARGV' fileA fileB`.

Answer (score 1):

To take an entirely different track from my other answer, this is the sort of problem where a shell function could make things clearer at the calling site:

```
if exactly_n_files 1 fileA fileB
then echo Exactly one file
else echo No or multiple files
fi
    
if exactly_n_files 23 *some*glob*here*
then echo "Exactly 23 files match glob"
else echo "More or fewer than 23 files match glob"
fi
```

For this you would want `exactly_n_files` defined thus:

```
exactly_n_files() {
  countdown=$1
  shift
  for f do
    if [ -f "$f" ] ; then
      countdown=$(( countdown - 1 ))
      [ "$countdown" = -1 ] && return 1
    fi
  done
  [ "$countdown" = 0 ]
}
```

Obviously, if this isn't constrained to POSIX shell, we should use `local` to constrain the internal variables, and we could make other simplifications:

```
exactly_n_files() {
  local countdown=$1
  shift
  for f do
    [[ -f $f ]] &&
      (( --countdown < 0 )) &&
        return 1
  done
  (( countdown == 0 ))
}
```

If you want to count the files, rather than simply check that there's exactly one, then a more general approach would be:

```
count_files() {
  count=0
  for f do
    if [ -f "$f" ] ; then
      count=$(( count + 1 ))
    fi
  done
}

count_files *some*glob*here*
case $count in
 0) echo NO FILES ;;
 1) echo ONE FILE ;;
 2) echo TWO FILES ;;
 *) echo MANY FILES
esac
```